# Alguém me ajuda com esse programa em Ansi C, programinha CRUD?

Tags: c, crud

Já experimentei apagar metade do código e deixar ele só com o primeiro bloco, mas fica dando erro nos operadores e em cada `scanf` que dou, sendo que preciso dar um jeito de atribuir os valores que pego dos `scanfs` e jogar dentro das devidas variáveis. Alguém me pode ajudar por favor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char _nome[20];
int _idade[9];
int _cpf[11];
main()
         {
            const int dez = 10;
            printf("O CRUD - cadastre o usuário, com nome, idade, cpf\n Nome: ");
                scanf("%s" &_nome);
            prinf("Idade: \n");
                scanf("%d" &_idade)
            printf("CPF(digite sem os pontos e sem traços): \n");
                scanf("%d" &_cpf);
            printf("usuário cadastrado com sucesso! \n Deseja alterar os dados de algum usuario? \n s ou n");
            scanf("s || n");
            if (scanf "s" == 1);
            else
            system("pause");
            printf("Qual dos dados do usuário você deseja alterar? \n Nome = 1 \n Idade = 2 \n CPF = 3 \n");
                if (scanf == 1);
                    function _Leitura(get_pointer_safety);
                    if (scanf == 2);
                        function _Alterar(get_pointer_safety);
                        if (scanf == 3);
                        function _Excluir();
                        else
                        system("pause")
                    else
                    system("pause");
                else
                system("pause");

         }
         function _Leitura(get_pointer_safety)
         {
            if return _nome = 1;
            getchar();
            putchar() &char = &putchar(&_nome);
            else
            system("pause");
         }
         function _Alterar()
         {
            printf("alterando dados do usuário... \n Nome: ");
            getchar();
            putchar(_Usuario());
            printf("Idade: \n");
                scanf("%d");
            printf("CPF: \n");
                scanf("%d");
            printf("Mais alguma coisa? \n s ou n");
                scanf("%s")
            if scanf("%s") == "s"
            return _a
            else
            system("pause");
         }
         function _Excluir()
         {

         }
```

Comment: Tem muita coisa erra ali Ramon. A sintaxis nas estruturas if esta errada e o scanf deve ser usado como funcao nao como objeto.

Comment: um dos motivos de eu recorrer aqui, é justamente as várias falhas que está dando a isso, mas tipo, eu e um amigo meu está fuçando aqui no código já faz há um bom tempo nessa madrugada, e não conseguimos obter muito sucesso não, por que ainda que eu declare antes do bloco main as funções ler, alterar e excluir, fica dando erro nas scanfs, tudo bem, eu só realmente queria um jeito de atribuir os valores que pego de cada função scanf declarada e botar nas devidas variáveis, já tentei o getchar e o putchar em cada printf mas ainda sim, não deu muito certo... =/

Comment: Cara aqui corregi um monte dos erros. Mas nao terminei o programa.

Comment: mano, não precisa terminar o programa, no caso, já ajudaria muito se tu mandasse o pastebin do que tu conseguiu resolver, ai dou uma olhada no que foi ajeitado e estudo um pouco mais afundo e dá certo também

Comment: testa ali esse código. Acepta a resposta e vota para que eu possa ganhar alguns pontos.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer as seguentes modificações:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char _nome[20];
//int _idade[9];
int _idade;
char _cpf[11];
const int dez = 10;
int _Leitura(void);
int _Alterar(void);

void main(){

    int opt = 0;
    char continuar = 'n';
    //const int dez = 10;

    printf("%s", "O CRUD - cadastre o usuário, com nome, idade, cpf\n Nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &_nome);
    printf("Idade: \n");
    scanf("%d", &_idade);
    printf("CPF(digite sem os pontos e sem traços): \n");
    scanf("%s", _cpf);
    printf("usuário cadastrado com sucesso! \n Deseja alterar os dados de algum usuario? \n s ou n");
    scanf("%s", &continuar);

    if (continuar == 's'); //            if (scanf "s" == 1);
        else
        system("pause");

    printf("Qual dos dados do usuário você deseja alterar? \n Nome = 1 \n Idade = 2 \n CPF = 3 \n");
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    if (opt == 1)
        _Leitura();
    if (opt == 2)
        _Alterar();
    if (opt == 3)
        1;
        //_Excluir();
    else
        system("pause");
              /*  else
                    system("pause");
                else
                system("pause");*/

}

int _Leitura(void){

    if (_nome == '1')
        getchar();
//            putchar() &char = &putchar(&_nome);
    else
        system("pause");
}

int _Alterar(void){

    char continua;
    int _a = 1;
    printf("alterando dados do usuário... \n Nome: ");
//            getchar();
            //putchar(_Usuario());
    scanf("%s", &_nome);
    printf("Idade: \n");
    scanf("%d", &_idade);
    printf("CPF: \n");
    scanf("%d", &_cpf);
    printf("Mais alguma coisa? \n s ou n");
    scanf("%s", &continua);
    if (continua == 's')
        return _a;
    else
        system("pause");
}

/*         function _Excluir()
         {

         }*/
```

Esse exemplo já compila, então vai te ajudar a entender a sintaxes e te permitir debugar ao rodar

Comment: cara vlw mano, e mesmo se não compilar aqui (o meu release do ubuntu é uma bosta) já ajuda em mta coisa, vlw mano sério mesmo

Comment: tbm tenho ubuntu. Sabe como compilar neh? >>>gcc nome_do_arquivo.c -o nome_do_arquivo e depois ./nome_do_arquivo

Comment: sim, to tentando aqui

Comment: cara, rodou aqui, valeu mano, ajudou muito aqui, vou ver aqui sobre a função opt que tu colocou uns opt dentro dos parâmetros IF, ainda não sei muito sobre, mas irei dar uma olhada mais afundo aqui, ta rodando aqui, valeu mano

Comment: De nada Ramon. Esse opt não é uma função é uma variavel onde se salva a opção digitada pelo usuario, é só para salvar 1, 2 ou 3 e depois comparar no if.